# Spark 2.1.0 structure streaming with local CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Just for learning the new Spark structure streaming with data, I had tried such experiment but no sure if I did anything wrong with the streaming function.

First, I started with something static and just use the simple text (csv) file coming with Spark 2.1.0:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load(".../spark2/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
df.show()
```

and I can get such reasonable output (under Zepplin).

```
+-------+---+
|    _c0|_c1|
+-------+---+
|Michael| 29|
|   Andy| 30|
| Justin| 19|
+-------+---+
```

and following the example, I just modified the codes to read the same file and supplied schema

```
val userSchema = new StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")

val csvDF = spark
  .readStream
  .schema(userSchema)      // Specify schema of the csv files
  .format("csv")
  .load(".../spark2/examples/src/main/resources/people.csv")
```

And no error message, so I was thinking to write the data to memory and see the results with the following codes:

```
val outStream = csvDF.writeStream
  .format("memory")
  .queryName("logs")
  .start()

sql("select * from logs").show(truncate = false)
```

However, with no error message, I kept get "empty output" with

```
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
+----+---+
```

The codes were tested under Zeppelin 0.7 and I am not sure if I missed anything here. Meanwhile, I had tried the example with from Apache Spark 2.1.0 official site with `$nc -lk 9999` and it ran very well.

May I learn if I did something wrong?

**[modified & tested]**

1. I tried and replicated the same file people.txt to people1.csv
   peopele2.csv people3.csv under one .../csv/ folder
2. `val csvDF = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).csv("/somewhere/csv")`
3. `csvDF.groupBy("name").count().writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start().awaitTermination()`

and I got this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|   name|count|
+-------+-----+
|Michael|    3|
|   Andy|    3|
| Justin|    3|
+-------+-----+
```

Therefore, I might not think it is a data **readstream()** issue ...

Answer (score 1):

1. The file name is `people.txt`, not `people.csv`. Spark will throw an error saying "Path does not exist". I just used Spark Shell to verify it.
2. The input path should be a directory. It doesn't make sense to use a file since this is a streaming query.

Comment: Appreciate. I tried people.csv as well without error message. But just still empty at final output.

Comment: I meant the correct file name should be `people.txt`. Did you happen to create a folder called `people.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 differences in the code:
1. The non-working one has output mode of "append" (default) but the working one has output mode of "complete".
2. The non-working selects records without aggregation but the working one has groupBy aggregation.

I suggest you switch to complete output mode and do a groupBy count to see if it fixes the problem.